# Opening multiple CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to open multiple excel files. My program throws error message "FileNotFoundError".  The file is present in the directory.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\GPA Calculations for CSM\\twentyfourteen"
files = os.listdir(path)
print (files)

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files: 
      df = pd.read_excel(f,'Internal', skiprows = 7) 
      print ("file name is " + f)
      print (df.loc[0][1])
      print (df.loc[1][1])
      print (df.loc[2][1])
```

Program gives error on `df = pd.read_excel(f,'Internal', skiprows = 7)`.

I opened the same file on another program (which opens single file) and that worked fine. Any suggestions or advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are all files in your path folder excel and does each have the same structure?

Comment: Can you display the particular error message you receive?  I want to rule out the possibility that you're pointing to the wrong file path.  Try adding the line "assert os.path.exists(f)" before you instantiate the data frame.  See if that gives you an error.

Comment: `os.listdir(path)` will return only the file names inside of your path. pass `os.path.join(path,f)` instead of f

Comment: When you are reading your file you are not passing it the path.  use `os.path.join` within `pd.read_excel`.

Answer (score 3):

`os.listdir` lists the filenames *relative* to the directory (path) you're giving as argument. Thus, you need to join the path and filename together to get the absolute path for each file. Thus, in your loop:

```
for filename in files:
    abspath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    <etc, replace f by abspath>
```